# No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort. Quickly

Tags: software-center, quickly, launchpad, bazaar

Create project:

https://launchpad.net/randomazer

input:

quickly submitubuntu.

Error:

Launchpad connection is ok
No Launchpad project set, leave blank to abort.

Comment: I was looking at http://askubuntu.com/questions/162043/error-with-quickly-submitubuntu and saw the the project name seemed to be "Convertik", the above URL refers to "convertik" ,but it's URL ends in randomazer rather than either of those. What `quickly create` command did you use? What is the contents of the file `.quickly`?

Comment: project = convertik 
version = 12.04
template = ubuntu-application 
bzrbranch = lp:~zaj87/randomazer/trunk 
ppa = randomazer

Comment: And how rename my quickly project? When I created him, he was named u1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on a project created with quickly and it has a lp-id line in its .quickly file. I believe this would be set with the `quickly config lp-project` command. I see that lp-id is absent in yours. I would expect that if your project name is convertik that the lp-id line would specify convertik and that the URL for the project would be launchpad.net/convertik, rather than launchpad.net/randomazer.

While there isn't a launchpad.net/convertik, there is a launchpad.net/~convertik. Perhaps that has been causing complications for you.

*Package* names are set in, for example, debian/control, debian/copyright debian/rules, and debian/changelog and may exist elsewhere in your project tree.

You mention above that the project name was originally u1. I assume some of the problems you are having has to do with this. You may have to start over with the quickly create command to create the project from scratch with the proper name and then carefully copy over the work you have done to the new project in order to get all of the project definition correct.

Comment: perhaps quickly configure lp-project?

Comment: rand@book:~/CannFest/convertik$ quickly submitubuntu
Получить настройки Launchpad
Launchpad connection is ok
https://launchpad.net/randomazer
convertik/convertikconfig.py file not found.

Comment: projectname/projectnameconfig.py does some work to set directories depending upon whether you are running the installed version or from the ~/CannFest/convertik directory. If there's a u1config.py file you could try to rename it. I don't know how many other places contain the project name that will have to change.